# How enable cache in a asp.net entityDataSource controle

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, caching, entitydatasource

how I can enable caching for a `EntityDataSource` object.
 is there anything like EnableCaching property of the SqlDataSource to entities?
 this cache is already enabled by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/sneak-peek-at-the-entitydatasource-control/):

> Like the LinqDataSource,  the EntityDataSource performs server side paging, and it does client side caching - of current AND original data. The original data is not stored as complete objects, but the minimal data necessary to reconstruct state when it's time to update. Updates happen, like any other data source, one at a time. So you have to pick an item, edit it and update it.

So it used cache automatically.